# The canonical map $\operatorname{Coind}_{H}^{G}(A)\to A$ is surjective?

Tags: group-cohomology, galois-cohomology

This question is about a claim found in Serre's *Galois Cohomology*

Let $H$ be an open subgroup of a profinite group $G$ and $A$ be a discrete $H$-module.

We then can form the co-induced module $\operatorname{Coind}_{G}^{H}(A)$ consisting of the maps
\begin{equation}
\operatorname{Coind}_{G}^{H}(A)=\{f\colon G\to A\:|\:f(hx)=h\cdot f(x)\:\forall h\in H, \forall x\in G\},
\end{equation}
which in addition are continuous. Now, we can consider the map $\pi\colon\operatorname{Coind}_{H}^{G}(A)\to A$ given by
\begin{equation}
\pi(f)=\sum_{x\in G/H} x\cdot f(x^{-1})
\end{equation}
and this is well-defined.

Serre claims this map is surjective.

To know this is a crucial step in finding the explicit inverse for the isomorphism given by Shapiro's Lemma, for example.

Now, how is this map surjective? Given $a\in A$, I think we could try and play "summing zero" to try and arrange it to be of that form but I can't imagine how one makes a construction that defines such an $f$ with all these desarible properties. Any hints? Thank you!

Comment: Define a map $f : G \to A$ that lies in the coinduced module, and for which each summand in $\pi$ is the desired element of $A$.

Comment: I don't get it. Wouldn't we have then $\pi(f)=a^{n}$, where $n=(G:H)$? I mean this is very confusing, if you would be kind enough to write an answer I will accept it. Or someone else :(

Comment: It is a sum, not a product.  This is not the appropriate site for writing out detailed proofs of standard facts; if you have trouble writing it up yourself, then it would probably be better to try it at [MSE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: The values of $f$ on the different $H$-cosets in $G$ have nothing to do with each other and can be assigned arbitrarily (subject to $H$-equivariance). Based on that, you can adjust @LSpice's suggestion to get rid of the $n$-fold repetition (and if still unclear, MSE is a more appropriate place to ask about that).

Comment: @nfdc23, oops, thanks.  I was thinking these were $\mathbb C[G]$-modules, so that it was OK to divide.

Comment: Thanks guys. Yea, I meant $n\cdot a$, sorry. Ok, I'll try more and if I do not succeed, MSE then.